# How to index a texture as a discrete lookup table from a shader?

Tags: opengl, textures, shader, glsl, gpgpu

I'm writing a shader in GLSL and I need to pass it a certain amount of information. The only practical way to pass this information is using a 1-D texture.
I'm creating the texture and setting `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` and `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` to `GL_NEAREST`
Now from the shader I need to access the texture so I'll be able to exactly index each and every number 3-value vector I put into it.
What is a sure-fire way to do this easily?
What I'm looking for is a formula which takes the size of the array and the index I want and give me the number in [0,1] which corresponds to the texel I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
idx/(size-1)
```

perhaps? Just make sure idx and size are floats first.

Comment: While that works (thanks to nearest neighbor), the correct way should be (idx + 0.5) / size.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that OpenGL 3.0 makes this need obsolete with the introduction of the `texelFetch()` functions which are also available with the extension `GL_EXT_gpu_shader4`